# how to make a search in Eclipse IDE in target folder

Tags: java, eclipse, search, target

this is must no be very complicated but i don't know how to search in "target" folder.
To be more precise, i'd like to search in : 
folder target/generated-sources (because, classes are created while building project)

I do CTL+H and then select :
"File search"/"Selected resource in Package explorer"

but result is always empty..

Comment: search with *.class extension

Comment: it does not work (files generated in folder target are 'classical' *.java extension files)

Comment: you should be copying source file also as a part of build. check if there are any filters set in the explorer which filters your file from the view

Comment: sorry, do not understand expression "copying source file also as a part of build"